# Jenkins agent intermittent connection failure after connecting to jenkins server

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins agent log

```
Apr 05, 2023 11:55:19 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Connected

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:44 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Terminated

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:44 AM hudson.remoting.Request$2 run

INFO: Failed to send back a reply to the request UserRequest:hudson.FilePath$CallableWith@599f753c: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@5d7d54a2:JNLP4-connect connection to jenkins.connect.com/18.0.0:9443" channel is already closed

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:44 AM hudson.remoting.Request$2 run

INFO: Failed to send back a reply to the request UserRequest:hudson.FilePath$Exists@22b09e1a: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@5d7d54a2:JNLP4-connect connection to jenkins.connect.com/18.0.0:9443": channel is already closed

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:44 AM hudson.remoting.Request$2 run

INFO: Failed to send back a reply to the request UserRequest:hudson.FilePath$CallableWith@405bfca0: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@5d7d54a2:JNLP4-connect connection to jenkins.connect.com/18.0.0:9443": channel is already closed

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:45 AM hudson.remoting.Request$2 run

INFO: Failed to send back a reply to the request UserRequest:hudson.node_monitors.SwapSpaceMonitor$MonitorTask@5a6cbedf: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@5d7d54a2:JNLP4-connect connection to jenkins.connect.com/18.0.0:9443": channel is already closed

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Performing onReconnect operation.

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: onReconnect operation completed.

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Locating server among \[https://jenkins.connect.fluke.com/\]

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:57 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve

INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: \[JNLP4-connect, Ping\]

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Agent discovery successful

Agent address: jenkins.connect.com

Agent port:    9443

Identity:      2b:e2:0c:85:2e:83:9e:12:24:9f:d1:e7:9b:33:56:4e

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Handshaking

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Connecting to jenkins.connect.fluke.com:9443

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:58 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:58 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.BIONetworkLayer$Reader run

INFO: Waiting for ProtocolStack to start.

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:58 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Remote identity confirmed: 2b:e2:0c:85:2e:83:9e:12:24:9f:d1:e7:9b:33:56:4e

Apr 05, 2023 11:55:59 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status

INFO: Connected
```

After upgrading jenkins version to 2.375.1 everything works fine for 4 months, then all of the sudden we are facing this issue

i tried to restart jenkins server and jenkins agent, restarted java process